# BigVideo Loop after n seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I need to the video after n seconds. Is there such parameter?

```
 BV.show('video/video1.mov',
                        {ambient: false, doLoop: false, altSource: 'video/video1.ogv'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the BigVideo page, you should be able to seek to the time you want through:

```
BV.getPlayer().currentTime(10) //10 seconds into the video.
```

you can also add an event when the video ends and seek back to the same time.

```
var player = BV.getPlayer();
var myFunc = function(){
  player.currentTime(10);
};
player.addEvent("ended", myFunc);
```